# How can I track detail view opens in Bixby?

Tags: bixby

I need to track which detail pages are opened and how often in result sets.

To do my own logging, I would need to send a javascript put command when the user opens the detail page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible right now in a straightforward way.

If you're feeling adventurous, you can try using `lazy-source`:

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/structure.property.lazy-source

Make sure that only the details view of your concept is using the lazy-property, so it isn't loaded on the list-of summaries, since as stated in the docs,

> Bixby calls the lazy source when the property is referenced either in a layout or dialog.

Comment: My thought exactly. NICE!

Comment: adventure is on the horizon!